# How can I obtain a value from a completion handler iOS Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, closures

Could someone please suggest or guide, how I can I return the `ProfileImage` obtained at `Location 1` in the below code and return it at `Location 2`. Would greatly appreciate your help. I've gone though other SO questions but none of them helped me.

```
static var profileImage : UIImage{

    get{
        let defaults        = UserDefaults.standard

        guard let imageData = defaults.object(forKey: "profileImage") as? NSData else{
            downloadAndSetProfileImage(completionHandler: { (profileImage) in

               // LOCATION 1:
               // PLEASE ADVISE HOW I CAN RETURN THE OBTAINED PROFILE IMAGE BELOW at LOCATION 2
            })

        }

        // LOCATION 2:
        // I would like to return the profileImage Here i.e. return profileImage

    }
    set (image){

        let defaults        = UserDefaults.standard
        let imageData : NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)! as NSData
        defaults.set(imageData, forKey: "profileImage")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not put asynchronous tasks into your getter. Instead you can use your optional `profileImage` computed property only for getting your image from the user defaults and make another async function to get the user profile which will return an image from the defaults if it's not nil, otherwise it will it attempt to download one. Like this:

```
static var profileImage : UIImage? {
    get {
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        guard let imageData = defaults.object(forKey: "profileImage") as? NSData else {
            return nil
        }
        return UIImage(data: Data(referencing: imageData))
    }
    set {
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        guard newValue != nil else {
            defaults.removeObject(forKey: "profileImage")
            return
        }
        let imageData = NSData(data: UIImagePNGRepresentation(newValue!)!)
        defaults.set(imageData, forKey: "profileImage")
    }
}

// Async function to retrieve profile image
func getProfileImage(completion: (_ image: UIImage?) -> ()) {
    guard ProfileAPI.profileImage == nil else {
        completion(ViewController.profileImage!)
        return
    }

    // Your image dowload funciton
    SomeImageDownloader.downloadImage("imagePath") { downloadedImage in
        completion(downloadedImage) // assuming downloadedImage can be nil
    }
}
```

To get your profile image you call:

```
getProfileImage { (image) in
    if let profileIage = image {
        // do something with it
    }
}
```

In the example `getProfileImage` combines the `profileImage` property with `downloadImage`. If `getProfileImage` has a value it will pass it immediately with the completion closure, otherwise it will call `downloadImage` and will pass the result when the task is over. Bottom line, you have a situation where an asynchronous task is needed, so in one way or another you need some kind of completion handler such as one in my example.

Answer (score 0):

```
static var profileImage : UIImage{

get{
    let defaults        = UserDefaults.standard

    guard let imageData = defaults.object(forKey: "profileImage") as? NSData else{
        downloadAndSetProfileImage(completionHandler: { (profileImage) in

           // LOCATION 1:
           return profileImage
        })

    }

    // LOCATION 2:
   return UIImage(data: (imageData as! NSData) as Data)

}
set (image){

    let defaults        = UserDefaults.standard
    let imageData : NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)! as NSData
    defaults.set(imageData, forKey: "profileImage")
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

You can use return operator

```
get{
   let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

   guard let imageData = defaults.object(forKey: "profileImage") as? NSData else{
     downloadAndSetProfileImage(completionHandler: { (profileImage) in

     return profileImage
     })
   }

   return UIImage(data: (imageData as! NSData) as Data)
}
```

If you receive value type of Data in your completionHandler, you should use method UIImage(data: profileImage)